# Order of iteration through dict.items()

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

**TLDR:**
*If I build a dictionary at two seperate times from the same data processed in the same way, should the order of dictionary.items() be the same each time?*

Hello,

I have dictionary `linked_strain_acc` which has about 2000 keys (strain names) and each key has another dictionary as a value (`data`).

```
linked_strain_acc = {'strain1' : {'gcf' : ['gcf1', 'gcf'..],
                                  'key2' : val2,
                                  .........},
                    'strain2' :  {.........},
                    ..........
                    'strain2000' :  {.........}}
```

I am iterating over a key (`'gcf'`) in each `data` dictionary, which contains a list of `gcf` ids.  I'm using the `gcf` ids to build a url for scraping, after testing that it's not already been scraped.

```
directory = r'C:\Users\u03132tk\.spyder-py3\scrape_dsmz\zip_files'
count = 0
start = time.time()
#allows you to stop and start
current_files = os.listdir(directory)
for strain,data in linked_strain_acc.items():
    for gcf in data['gcf']:
        count+=1
        filename = f'{strain}__{gcf}.zip'
        if filename not in current_files:
            download_url = f'https://antismash-db.secondarymetabolites.org/output/{gcf}/{gcf}.zip'
            response = requests.get(download_url)
            with open(fr'{directory}\{filename}', "wb") as infile:
                infile.write(response.content)
            print (f'downloaded {strain}, {gcf}')
        else:
            print (f'{strain}, {gcf} already scraped')
        if count%50 == 0:
            print (f'downloaded {count} jsons - script has been running for {round((time.time() - start)/60, 1)} minutes')
```

**Question**

I have already scraped about 1500 of the `gcf` urls and downloaded the files (out of the 2000ish total).  When I ran it again this morning, instead of printing '{strain}, {gcf} already scraped' for the first 1500 print statements, its alternating between a couple of '{strain}, {gcf} already scraped' print messages and 'downloaded {strain}, {gcf}' print statements.  This implies that the order of the linked_strain_acc dictionary has changed.

I made this dictionary from a CSV file which was processed in exactly the same way each time to make `linked_strain_acc`.  Why would the order of the dict change, or am I missing something?  I know that dict key/val order isn't ordered by e.g. alphabet or size, but I though it would be maintained when it is built from exactly the same data.

Thanks!

Comment: What version of Python are you on? Dictionaries are insertion-ordered after 3.7.

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply - I'm 3.7, what does insertion ordered mean?

Comment: Are you sure your URL's are correct? E.g. `{gcf}/{gcf}` at the end of your download when other strings all seem to be {strain} {gcf}. The Python dictionary order for items is fixed for several versions now; it seems more likely that a problem is produced by manual web-scraping while building URL's, or rebuilding CSV's, or using os.listdir() for something else, which has an arbitrary order.

Comment: Hi kcsquared, I'm as sure as I can be - I'm scraping them from an online db with a 'download file' option that has a '...../gcf/gcf.zip' url format.  I'm getting the gcfs themselves from a summary csv file of query results output by the same db, and all my files seems to be downloading fine (as I've got 1500 of them and having manually checked a couple they look ok).  The confusing thing is that webscraping shouldn't even be started in these cases - the presence of the file in the directory should block it starting (and the order of os.listdir() shouldn't impact tests of presence).

Comment: Also, I am not rebuilding the csv, it is always working from the same one and processing it in the same way (i'm just rerunning the same script so nothing changes - it just checks what it has already found).

Answer (score 0):

In older versions, python was using string pools to efficiently store longer strings by pooling shorter common segments. Every time you create a string, it may change the pool, and hence the order. The strings you dynamically create in

```
download_url = f'https://antismash-db.secondarymetabolites.org/output/{gcf}/{gcf}.zip'
```

may change the pool depending on your starting point. For reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning

Comment: Hi Oguzkhan, thanks for the interesting idea - I'll have to have a google about pooling, never heard of it.  However, surely this wouldn't be an issue here as gcf is defined before the f-string?  and the f-string is not determining the order through which the dict is iterated?

Comment: Still, it can change the order. I am unsure if there is a way to visualize/debug the interning pool though. I am happy to be able to help!